# Spring Config-server throwing 404 on config file only from my git repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I've been following [this microservices tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq85GschdLw) and launching the config server with these properties:

```
spring.application.name=configuration-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/sylleryum/microservices-config-server

spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
```

the config server runs fine, but when trying to access it through http://localhost:8888/order-service/default i get a 404.

if i change the spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri to https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/microservices-config-server 
which has exactly the same files, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this response is very late, but still posting it as I faced the same issue but had to spend sometime to resolve it.

#1 Changing git uri to https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/microservices-config-server works

- It could be because the above uri is a public git repo and you would not to provide any credentials

#2 Check if you are providing URI of a private git repository, if so - we need to use a personal access token (generated in github) instead of using the github password.

**Steps to check if you are using a private github repo :**

- Select repository -> settings -> Danger Zone -> Change Visibility
- Shows "Change to Public" if you are in a private repo else shows "Change to Private"

**Generate Personal Access Token :**

- Profile -> Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Access Tokens -> Tokens(classic) -> Generate New Token -> New Personal Access Token (classic)
- Provide all the required selections and proceed for token generation.
- Use the above generated token as a value for spring.cloud.config.server.git.password configuration in your config server.

Answer (score 0):

found out, apparently the config files have to be on master branch